Coloring Kakeya's Needle
My question concerns a simple observation I made recently while working on the Perspective Three-Point Problem. I am wondering if anybody has a reference for the claim I am about to make concerning colors.
Animated GIF: 
The animated GIF shows the needle in Kakeya’s Needle Problem moving around inside the deltoid curve. However, I’ve colored the needle using three colors, and this coloring change as the needle moves. Here is a somewhat cute fact: every point inside the deltoid is on three needles (well-known), and is on a red portion of one of these needles, a green portion of another needle, and a blue portion of yet another needle.

Where I say "needles," it would be more correct to say "needle positions."
